# How to access data attribute different from value from datalist html tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<input list="items" id="item"> 
<datalist id="items">
   <option data-value="123">Uno </option>
   <option data-value="456">Dos </option>
</datalist>
```

Above is the html structure

Comment: Why not use the `value` attribute?

Comment: data-value is used to get the link or any other value which could be hidden from the user.

Comment: There is a value attribute that does the same thing

Comment: @user2182349, No it doesn't. Your display value can be different from the hyperlink you want to redirect. You cannot use links like google with value%newvalue% every where. If you have value=new link, it will redirect as new%link if same value is used .

Answer (score 0):

```
inputBox.addEventListener('change', function (e) {

    var val = $('#item').val()
    console.log(val);
    var dataValue = $('#items option').filter(function () {
        return this.value == val;
    }).data('value');//xyz is data-xyz
    //var msg = xyz ? 'xyz=' + xyz : 'No Match';
    if (dataValue) {
        window.location.href = `/${dataValue}`;
    }


});
```

Creating this post for future reference new to this.
Thank to the this [jsfiddle creator](https://%20https://jsfiddle.net/qf9kvan0/3/)